# text file processing PHP laravel

Tags: php, laravel, csv, text-files

How can I read/process data that is taken from a text file which have line breaks for each new record following is the sample. I want it to upload and process the lines and insert into DB, so I just want to know how to read it

> 0603201614020000180502
>   0603201614020000167002
>   0603201614020000132701
>   0603201614020000132402

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read it into an array like `$lines = file('filename.txt');` and loop over it to do your "processing"